# Was Jesus supposed to have an actual part in "Iron Sky 2"? If so, why was it cut?

Tags: iron-sky-the-coming-race

One of the early trailers for *Iron Sky: The Coming Race* had Jesus wielding a machine gun.

Unless the copy I watched was cut, there was no Jesus in the final movie. Was he supposed to have an actual plotline, or scene? If so, what was it and why was it cut off?

Googling stuff like `iron sky 2 Jesus interview` brings up [this interview](https://lrmonline.com/news/iron-sky-the-coming-race-conspiracy-theories-spin-offs-and-more-an-interview-with-director-timo-vuorensola/), which gives the feeling the makers weren't sure about what they were going to do back in 2014 (Jesus could simply not have made it), but it also talks about the Putin dance scene, which was included (albeit briefly) in the intro of the movie.

> And it also actually helps quite a lot that we did these little promos with the Jesus, and we had Putin, and then we had this Palin kind of character. And all of these characters were sort of doing those little promos helped us also to define the story, so they were used also as the funding tools because with those tools we were able to go on to the financiers and say, “Okay. This is the look and feel we’re going to go for,” and then we were able to get money.

Is there a more definite reason as to why Jesus why left out of the picture? Was it replaced by the Jobsists story arc? Something else?

Comment: That's a *very* odd trailer.

Comment: @Wikis no argument there. They were playing on the WTFness of the first movie, I think; this trailer is actually closer in time to the first one than the second one. In all fairness, _Iron Sky_ was great and fun, _The Coming Race_ was pretty meh.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read any explanation from the creators, so this is pure speculation.

Jesus was probably going to be one of the Vril villains, but he was replaced by pope Urban II. Both characters are played by the same actor, Jukka Hilden.

While a lot of evil has been done in the name of christianity, Jesus himself can't really be blamed for that. Urban II, however, started the first crusade.

Comment: As you write, this is pure speculation.

Comment: Hadn't noticed it was the same actor. Speculation, sure, but good catch anyway, sounds plausible. Waiting for the official answer, if we ever get one.